# Change The Value of InputFromTextBox SharePoint control using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

**Dear All,**

Can anyone show me how to change (clear) the value of InputFromTextBox SharePoint with full rich text enabled, I can't reach to the object by its id hence it puts the text in a seperate IFRAME, gives it an ID [Control ID + iframe], when I access the IFRAME I can't reach the inner tag hence innerhtml property = ""

I'm turning around myself since yesterday, it must be easy but I'm soo down now.

**Thanks for help**

Answer (score 0):

You can use function defined [here](http://blog.markuso.com/posts/9/using-javascript-to-access-a-list-form-field-in-sharepoint-designer/) or [here](http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/archive/2009/07/06/setting-sharepoint-form-fields-using-javascript.aspx) to reference form field.

Remember that with full rich text enabled cleared value is `<div></div>` if i remember correctly.